# how to fetch and store http response coming as object(not sobject)

Tags: httpresponse

[image: debug log]
I am fetching these(Actors, awards, genre, lanuage) details from htpresponse "results" of an api.

But these values are coming as object. I want to show these values on Salesforce UI. since these values are in for of object, how can i map these on salesforce page.
code

```java
List<String> v = new List<String>();  
v.add('Actors');  
v.add('Awards');  
v.add('Genre');  
v.add('Language'); 

Map<String, object> results = (Map<String, object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(obj3.getBody()); 

for(Integer i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
    object y = '';
    y = results.get(v[i]);
    System.debug(y);       
}
```

Also, I want to invoke this API via button on Salesforce page of my custom object and store response. Like user input name of movie and receive actors, awards etc details as response. Please suggest ways to invoke API behind button.

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking. Can you please explain more? Just [edit] the question to explain what you are trying to do and where you are stuck.

Comment: thanks for your response! I am trying to test outbound call for POC/learning purpose. Invoked an API,received response. want to show same on salesfocre page.

Comment: If you were able to define HOW you want to show the results, that would help a lot. lwc component, vf page, write to sobject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling apex and I see no reference to any sort of component method that you would use to display this response.

So I'm going to assume that you are going to be creating a record with four fields filled by each of these values:

(Assuming you have made the custom objects and fields referenced below)

```
Map<String,String> propertyToFieldMap = new Map<String,String>{ 
  'Actors'  =>'Actors__c',
  'Awards'  =>'Awards__c',
  'Genre'   =>'Genre__c',
  'Language'=>'Language__c'
};

Map<String, object> results = (Map<String, object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(obj3.getBody()); 

Actor_Stats__c stats = new Actor_Stats__c();
for(String property : propertyToFieldMap.keySet()){
  stats.put(propertyToFieldMap.get(property), (String)results.get(property) );
}

insert stats;
```

You could use a custom inner class to cleanly map the response, but it's pretty short and simple and you get double use of the response field mapping to sObject field mapping (to extract the result + map to fields), so this way is probably the simplest you can have.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I want to invoke this api via button on Salesforce page of my custom object and store response. Like user input name of movie and receive actors, awards etc details as response. please sugget ways to invoke api behind button.

Comment: That's not the question you asked. I suggest you add this information to the question above so you don't waste anyone else's time.

Comment: added, thanks@caspar

Comment: I was able to call via visualforce page. I am taking Name as input and passing that to my api call and able to save response from api in salesforce. httpresponse coming as object is cast typed in string and aastored in custom objects fields as explained by casper in his example.